# Счетчик в canvas

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Объясните пожайлуста, почему счетчик работает непонятно как. Я хотел чтобы он считал количество удалённых квадратов из массива.

```js
function animate() {  
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
  var score = document.getElementById('score');
  var count = 0;

  function Square (x, y, w, h) {
   this.x = Math.random() * 620;
   this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
   this.r = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    this.g = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    this.b = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);

    this.rgba = "rgba("+this.r+", "+this.g+", "+this.b+", 1)";

    this.draw = function() {
      ctx.fillStyle = this.rgba;
      ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 20, 20);
      this.update();
    }

    this.update = function() {
      this.y += Math.random() * 2;
    }
  }
  
  var squares = [];

  function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientWidth);
    for(i = 0; i < squares.length; i++)
        squares[i].draw();
    update();
  }

  function update() {
    for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
      squares[i].update();
    }
  }

  setInterval(function(){
    
    squares.push(new Square(0, 0, 20, 20))
  },1000);

  setInterval(draw, 20);
    
    var isCursorInSquares = function(x, y, squares) {
    return  x > squares.x && x < squares.x + squares.w + 8 && 
            y > squares.y && y < squares.y + squares.h + 20;
    }

  canvas.onclick = function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX;
        y = e.pageY;

    for(var i = squares.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if(isCursorInSquares(x, y, squares[i])) 
          delete squares.splice(i, 1);
          score.innerHTML = count++;
    }
  }
}

document.body.onload = animate;
```

```html
<doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Qualium Systems Javascript test task </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    <style>
      canvas {        
        background: yellow;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <button onclick=""> Start </button>
      <button onclick=""> Stop </button>
      <span> Score: <span id="score"> 0 </span> </span>
    </div>
    <canvas width="640" height="480" id="canvas"></canvas>      
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы банально забыли оформить условие в блок кода. Без этого у Вас код при каждом клике считал количество квадратов и добавлял их в `score`.

```
if(isCursorInSquares(x, y, squares[i])) 
{
     delete squares.splice(i, 1);
     score.innerHTML = count++;
}
```

И лучше используйте значения события `e.offsetX` и `e.offsetY`, что бы не городить поправки для расположения `canvas`.

```
var isCursorInSquares = function(x, y, squares) 
{
    return  x > squares.x && x < (squares.x + squares.w) && 
            y > squares.y && y < (squares.y + squares.h);
}

canvas.onclick = function(e) 
{
    var x = e.offsetX;
        y = e.offsetY;

    for(var i = squares.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) 
    {
        if(isCursorInSquares(x, y, squares[i])) 
        {
            delete squares.splice(i, 1);
            score.innerHTML = count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, вот только если использую x = e.offsetX и y = e.offsetY, всё равно где-то координаты сбиваются? С поправками работает точнее.